# Build and run Go using cgo using bazel

Tags: c, go, shared-libraries, bazel, cgo

There is simple cgo project available on this [page](https://www.thegoldfish.org/2019/04/using-c-libraries-from-go/). It relies on pre-built c shared library and it works great when using `go build`, with minor changes to make it buildable.

I wanted to use Bazel for the same thing.

Used source code is same as on this [github link](https://github.com/timhughes/cgoexample), without using hello.c file.
With all said, final code looked like below.

```c
/*
 * person.c
 * Copyright (C) 2019 Tim Hughes
 *
 * Distributed under terms of the MIT license.
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "person.h"

APerson *get_person(const char *name, const char *long_name)
{

    APerson *fmt = malloc(sizeof(APerson));
    fmt->name = name;
    fmt->long_name = long_name;

    return fmt;
};
```

```c
/*
 * person.h
 * Copyright (C) 2019 Tim Hughes
 *
 * Distributed under terms of the MIT license.
 */

#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

typedef struct APerson
{
    const char *name;
    const char *long_name;
} APerson;

APerson *get_person(const char *name, const char *long_name);

#endif /* !PERSON_H */
```

```golang
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -lperson
#include "person.h"
*/
import "C"

import (
    "github.com/kubernetes/klog"
)

type (
    Person C.struct_APerson
)

func GetPerson(name string, long_name string) *Person {
    return (*Person)(C.get_person(C.CString(name), C.CString(long_name)))
}

func main() {
    klog.Info("it is running")
    var f *Person
    f = GetPerson("tim", "tim hughes")
    klog.Infof("Hello Go world: My name is %s, %s.\n", C.GoString(f.name), C.GoString(f.long_name))
}
```

Bazel build file is below.

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary", "go_library")

go_library(
    name = "listing_lib",
    srcs = [
        "person.c",
        "person.h",
        "runner.go",
    ],
    cgo = True,
    clinkopts = ["-Lpersons/listing -lperson"],
    copts = ["-g -Wall"],
    importpath = "github.com/example/project/persons/listing",
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
    deps = ["@com_github_kubernetes_klog//:klog"],
)

go_binary(
    name = "listing",
    embed = [":listing_lib"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Still when building by running `bazelisk build //persons/listing`, error happens and it is general linker error.

```
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lperson
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
compilepkg: error running subcommand /usr/bin/gcc: exit status 1
```

I need few things to clear out.

- are c libraries built automatically? My assumption is that those are not.
- if not, then why `-L.` is not working if built lib is same folder as go file? Assumption is that bazel does not see library in source folder, but is looking in wrong location.
- is it possible to use cc_library rule to build shared library that can be used in cgo? if so, how to connect those?

Comment: I don't think current working directory is what you think it is. Can you try `#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR} -lperson`?

Comment: @JimB Flag `-L${SRCDIR}` for some reason gives double folder as `-Lpersons/listing/persons/listing`. This happens after `gazelle update` command. Also, working directory should be in bazel-out folder, which again should have absolute paths. I am thinking this is all related to some Bazel issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are c libraries built automatically? My assumption is that those are not.

Why? Tests from the offical repo shows, that it is [done automatically](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/09088926548d32dab7748d233f8e20a318868275/tests/core/cgo/BUILD.bazel#L10)

> is it possible to use cc_library rule to build shared library that can be used in cgo? if so, how to connect those?

See example from [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/09088926548d32dab7748d233f8e20a318868275/tests/core/cgo/BUILD.bazel#L70)

Comment: Thanks for example, I will let you know if it works with this simple project.

Comment: I am accepting this answer. I still need to test `cc_library` rules, but that will have to wait.

Automated build works fine, if one does not follow official cgo documentation. Problem with pure go is linking with library, and since .so file is in same folder where .go file is, all works great. Bazel automatically determines where built .so file is, therefore annotation in comment above `import "C"` (just header file is needed) is not important for my simple example.